# Graphical Tree Creation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm fluent with CSS/HTML
Decent with CSS3 and HTML5 and Jquery.
My project is using Asp.net MVC, LINQ, Razor.

Just incase the later is important.

I am trying to create a graphical tree for the user.  I have never attempted anything like this ever before so I am not sure where to even begin.

I know I want it to be a top down tree.  A single node at top cascading into multiple nodes at the bottom.

There will always be 4 levels (Department, Function, Process, Procedure) and will eventually be 5 levels.

I'm sure there is going to be a lot of math involved with this.  If someone can point me in the right direction, or maybe there is a tutorial out there.  I would be much appreciated.

***  As a side note, this will likely have an impact.  This tree is being put into an already responsive website.

Barring my artistic skills this is what im trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if it included an example of what sort of output you're looking to produce. An image of a tree similar to your intended result would more than suffice -- without such an example, it's difficult to understand what you're looking to accomplish clearly enough to offer advice.

Comment: @AaronMiller point taken.  I have added an images to better describe what i am looking to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Have a look at [**`OrgChart`**](http://demo.orgchartcomponent.com/) for ASP.NET. It seems like it satisfies your requirements, but be prepared to pay USD200- USD400 licence fee based on your team/project setup.
2. Use the great, freely available [**`Infovis`**](http://philogb.github.io/jit/index.html) JavaScript visualization toolkit. It has a component called [**`SpaceTree`**](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html) that can draw trees just like you need.
3. Use properly positioned divs with borders for representing the tree nodes, and [**`jsPlumb`**](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/jquery/demo.html) to create connections between nodes.